# Auto download and install apk in android O

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to implement auto download and install apk in my application using file provider. For android version less than Oreo it works fine but getting problem while running app on device with android 8.0 and above. It works fine till Nougat, but doesn't works with Oreo. Downloading apk from server working fine but fails to install new apk.
Here is my code.

```
File file, folder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Utility.checkPermissionCamera(Main2Activity.this);
    Utility.checkPermissionInstall(Main2Activity.this);
        String fileName = "AutoDownloadApplication.apk";
        folder = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
        Logger.e("FOLDER", " " + folder);
        file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
        Log.e("File ", "" + file);

        final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Main2Activity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        Logger.e("Check URI ", "" + uri);
    if (Utility.checkPermissionCamera(Main2Activity.this)) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(StaticConstant.DOWNLOADAPK));
        request.setDescription("Downloading New Apk");
        request.setTitle(Main2Activity.this.getString(R.string.app_name));
        //set destination
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Main2Activity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileName);

        // get download service and enqueue file

            final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
            //set BroadcastReceiver to install app when .apk is downloaded
            BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    install.setDataAndType(uri,
                            manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
                    startActivity(install);
                }
                    unregisterReceiver(this);
                }
            };
            //register receiver for when .apk download is compete
            registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="MyPackageName">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="MyPackageName.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

Here is the file_paths xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="Download" path="Android/data/MyPackageName/files/Download"/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>` permission in Manifest.xml first.

We should check the result of `getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()` if the SDK version is equal or large than 26.

The code is below:

```
private void checkIsAndroidO() {  
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {  
    boolean result = getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls();  
    if (result) {  
      installApk();
    } else {  
      // request the permission 
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES}, INSTALL_PACKAGES_REQUESTCODE);  
    }  
  } else {
    installApk();  
  }  
}

@Override  
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {  
  super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

  switch (requestCode) {  
    case INSTALL_PACKAGES_REQUESTCODE:  
      if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {  
        installApk();  
      } else {  
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);  
        startActivityForResult(intent, GET_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);  
      }  
    break;  
  }  
}

@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

  switch (requestCode) {  
    case GET_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES:  
      checkIsAndroidO();  
      break;  

    default:  
      break;  
  }  
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about FileProvider implementation in details how it works from below article:

[https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/)

Answer (score 0):

The soluciton of JohnWatsonDev Worked perfectly!
Just one thing, to call your app directly, is just put:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
```

Before call

```
startActivityForResult(intent, GET_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);
```